# Adding watermark to video is extremely slow

Tags: ios, swift, avfoundation, avcomposition, avvideocomposition

I am using AVComposition to render a watermark to a video. This process takes around 15 seconds, which doesn't seem ok for a 20 seconds video.
My export settings are:

```
let exporter = AVAssetExportSession.init(asset: mixComposition, presetName: AVAssetExportPresetHighestQuality)
    exporter?.outputURL = outputPath
    exporter?.outputFileType = AVFileType.mp4
    exporter?.shouldOptimizeForNetworkUse = true
    exporter?.videoComposition = mainCompositionInst
    DispatchQueue.main.async {
        exporter?.exportAsynchronously(completionHandler: {

            if exporter?.status == AVAssetExportSessionStatus.completed {
                completion(true, exporter)
            }else{
                completion(false, exporter)
            }

        })
    }
```

This is how I add the watermark:

```
    //Creating image layer
    let overlayLayer = CALayer()
    let overlayImage: UIImage = image
    overlayLayer.contents = overlayImage.cgImage
    overlayLayer.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: size.width, height: size.height)
    overlayLayer.contentsGravity = kCAGravityResizeAspectFill
    overlayLayer.masksToBounds = true

    //Creating parent and video layer
    let parentLayer = CALayer()
    let videoLayer = CALayer()
    parentLayer.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: size.width, height: size.height)
    videoLayer.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: size.width, height: size.height)
    parentLayer.addSublayer(videoLayer)
    parentLayer.addSublayer(overlayLayer)

    //Adding those layers to video
    composition.animationTool = AVVideoCompositionCoreAnimationTool(postProcessingAsVideoLayer: videoLayer, in: parentLayer)
}
```

and this is how I eventually transform my video:

```
 let videoLayerInstruction = AVMutableVideoCompositionLayerInstruction.init(assetTrack: videoTrack!)
    let videoAssetTrack = videoAsset.tracks(withMediaType: AVMediaType.video)[0]
    var videoAssetOrientation = UIImageOrientation.up
    var isVideoAssetPortrait = false
    let videoTransform = videoAssetTrack.preferredTransform

    if videoTransform.a == 0 && videoTransform.b == 1.0 && videoTransform.c == -1.0 && videoTransform.d == 0 {
        videoAssetOrientation = .right
        isVideoAssetPortrait = true
    }
    if videoTransform.a == 0 && videoTransform.b == -1.0 && videoTransform.c == 1.0 && videoTransform.d == 0 {
        videoAssetOrientation = .left
        isVideoAssetPortrait = true
    }
    if videoTransform.a == 1.0 && videoTransform.b == 0 && videoTransform.c == 0 && videoTransform.d == 1.0 {
        videoAssetOrientation = .up
    }
    if videoTransform.a == -1.0 && videoTransform.b == 0 && videoTransform.c == 0 && videoTransform.d == -1.0 {
        videoAssetOrientation = .down
    }

    videoLayerInstruction.setTransform(videoAssetTrack.preferredTransform, at: kCMTimeZero)

    //Add instructions
    mainInstruction.layerInstructions = [videoLayerInstruction]
    let mainCompositionInst = AVMutableVideoComposition()
    let naturalSize : CGSize!
    if isVideoAssetPortrait {
        naturalSize = CGSize(width: videoAssetTrack.naturalSize.height, height: videoAssetTrack.naturalSize.width)
    } else {
        naturalSize = videoAssetTrack.naturalSize
    }
```

So my question now is, how can I improve the performance of merging the watermark to my video? 15 seconds is totally unacceptable for any kind of end-user. Furthermore, I need to transport this video over the internet, so the loading screen would show its beauty more than a total of approximately twenty seconds.

Comment: Maybe I'm just not up-to-date on video codecs, but decoding, modifying, then re-encoding faster than the playback time on a phone seems pretty good to me. Could it be that you have unrealistic performance expectations? What makes you think that it could be any faster?

Comment: This could be the case. How long does it normally take to render a 17MB Video on an iPhone? I see snapchat and Instagram rendering the same video in 2 seconds. I compared other rendering times with mine and it seems that there is still a lot of unleashed potential.

Comment: If you are rendering 1080p or higher resolution it's not so unacceptable. Snapchat and Instagram use low resolution for rendering speed and file size. @JohannaNoobie

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per the [Apple Documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avasynchronousciimagefilteringrequest), try using the class `AVAsynchronousCIImageFilteringRequest`

> ### Overview
>
> You use this class when creating a composition for Core Image filtering with the init(asset:applyingCIFiltersWithHandler:) method. In that method call, you provide a block to be called by AVFoundation as it processes each frame of video, and the block’s sole parameter is a AVAsynchronousCIImageFilteringRequest object. Use that object both to the video frame image to be filtered and allows you to return a filtered image to AVFoundation for display or export. Listing 1 shows an example of applying a filter to an asset.
>
> ```
>     let filter = CIFilter(name: "CIGaussianBlur")!
>     let composition = AVVideoComposition(asset: asset, applyingCIFiltersWithHandler: { request in
>
>     // Clamp to avoid blurring transparent pixels at the image edges
>     let source = request.sourceImage.imageByClampingToExtent()
>     filter.setValue(source, forKey: kCIInputImageKey)
>
>     // Vary filter parameters based on video timing
>     let seconds = CMTimeGetSeconds(request.compositionTime)
>     filter.setValue(seconds * 10.0, forKey: kCIInputRadiusKey)
>
>     // Crop the blurred output to the bounds of the original image
>     let output = filter.outputImage!.imageByCroppingToRect(request.sourceImage.extent)
>
>     // Provide the filter output to the composition
>     request.finishWithImage(output, context: nil)
> })
> ```

There is a [tutorial in Objective C](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/avfoundation/avasynchronousciimagefilteringrequest) that may be a good resource as well.

Comment: Hello, thanks a lot for this answer. I will look into this, when I am at home. - No worries, you will receive the bounty.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54652637/when-i-am-exporting-video-then-cifilter-not-working-avmutablevideocomposition have a look can you please suggest me what i am doing wrong?